# find a matching string in columns in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data in the following order

```
Movie_title  views   likes  genres   actor_name   director_name
xxc  -      -   455  -  ...   Action     ...            ...
nnj  -      -        -       Funny 
hhs  -      -        -      news
jjs  -      -        -        Action
uus  -      -        -       ...
yys  -      -        -        ...
```

I want to display the movie_title and views of only 'Action' values in genres column.
Like

```
Movie_title  views  genres
...                 Action
...                 Action
```

Comment: `df[df.genres=='Action']`

Comment: Thank You bro for comment. And how to display movie title column with this also. Please

Answer (score 0):

As Ch3steR already said to you in comments, your filter is done by checking df.genres == "action".

You can do before that something like

```
columns = ["movie", "genre"]
df = df[columns]
```

Which will result in a df made by these two columns (or more if added), after that you can start filtering the genre column